# a timed transition between scenes in Xcode

Tags: xcode, transition, scene, timed

I am using a storyboard on xcode and I need help making a timed transition between 2 scenes. I want the game to open on one scene and after 5 seconds go to the actual game scene. Any help would be very appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NSTimer for that:

In the header (.h) file you create the timer:

```
NSTimer *timer;
```

In the .m file you can use this code:
(above @interface put #import "SecondView.h")

```
-(void)viewScene {
SecondView *second = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
second.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentViewController:second animated:true completion:nil];
}

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(viewScene) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Good luck!

Comment: I dont have a secondview.h file so i am getting an error from writing the #import "SecondView.h" code

Comment: The SecondView.h is an example. It stands for the header file of your actual game view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about splash screen(image) then you could do that only saving three image named `Default.png`, `Default@2x.png`, `Default-568h@2x.png` in the project directory. There are for normal screen (320*480), 3.5 retina screen (640*960), 4.0 retina screen (640*1136) images.